# Azure pipeline BatchScript task is not running the script on the machine its deploying to

Tags: azure, batch-file, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure deployment pipeline that copy files to an azure VM hosted on my account using this task:

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    azureSubscription: 'qa-serverside-snapshots'
    Destination: 'AzureVMs'
    storage: 'serversidesnapshotsdiag'
    enableCopyPrerequisites: true
    resourceGroup: 'SERVERSIDE-SNAPSHOTS'
    vmsAdminUserName: $(username)
    vmsAdminPassword: $(password)
    TargetPath: 'C:\Git\serverside-snapshots'
```

The issue is I run into errors pertaining to not being able to write to a file because it is in use by the service running on the machine. So what I want to do is run a bat script that stops the service on the azure VM. Here was my attempt:

```
- task: BatchScript@1
  inputs:
    filename: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\stopPM2.bat'
    workingFolder: 'C:\Git\serverside-snapshots'
```

"stopPM2.bat" literally just contains `pm2 stop myservice`. The issue is, when the bat file gets ran, I get this error:

```
C:\Git\serverside-snapshots>pm2 stop myservice
'pm2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I definitely have PM2 installed on the server I'm deploying to. It looks like the bat file isn't actually getting run on the VM I'm trying to deploy to, but its running on the temporary VM that the pipeline in running stuff on. So my question is, how do I get a bat script to run on the VM I'm deploying to so I can stop the service before copying files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BatchScript` runs **on the build agent**.

You need to use `PowerShell on Target Machine` or `SSH on Target Machine` to invoke something on a remote machine.

Comment: I ended up finding that task right before you posted this haha. Will accept this as the answer. Thanks